# How to get index of numpy multidimensional array in reverse order?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

For example I have this np.array:

```
[[True, True, False, False]
[True, False, True, False]
[False, True, False, True]
[False, False, True, True]]
```

I want to get the the first index that is True in each row but counting from the back of the row. So expected output is a (4,) array corresponding to each row:

```
[1,  # First index that is True is at index 1
 2,  # First index that is True is at index 2
 3,  # First index that is True is at index 3
 3]  # First index that is True is at index 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = np.array(
    [[True, True, False, False],
     [True, False, True, False],
     [False, True, False, True],
     [False, False, True, True]]
)

idx = a.shape[1] - 1 - np.argmax(a[:,::-1], axis=1)
```

`np.argmax()` will find the index of the highest value (for each row with axis=1). Since `True` is equivalent to 1 and `False` to 0, it'll record the index of the first `True` value. Simply reverse the rows so you find the "last" one and then substract this from the row length to account for the fact that you're counting backwards.

Answer (score 0):

you can use python to reversea row and find an element: `row.reverse()` and `row.find(True)`. in numpy you can use `numpy.flip(row)` to reverse a row and `numpy.where(row == True)` to find an element in a row.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[True, True, False, False],
[True, False, True, False],
[False, True, False, True],
[False, False, True, True]])

result = []
for row in x:
    row = np.flip(row)
    index = np.where(row == True)
    result.append(index[0][0])
print(result)
```